# Create all combinations of a word through spaces in the Console Application

Tags: vb.net, console

I'm trying to experiment with this, http://gyazo.com/8190a3c98a520bbeb77335e05ea5a636 (a visual basic console application). I want it to allow the user to enter in a word such, and have the console reply with it in all spaced combinations possible, so:

Say i'm using the word TEST, for example it would be created spaced out like this:

```
T EST
T E ST
T E S T
TE ST
TES T
T ES T
```

And so on... (Such as every combination it can be spaced out with multiple spaces or not)

Is this possible through the Console Application?

Comment: What code have you tried so far to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

When counting, you start at the lowest digit.  You start with that digit at zero and you count up until you reach the highest value for that digit, like this: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`.  Then, once you reach the highest value, you have to add a second digit (e.g. `10`).  Then you go from lowest to highest again on the lowest digit again (e.g. `10 - 19`) before incrementing the second digit again (e.g. 20).  In that way, once you reach `999`, you will have listed every possible combination of values in a three digit number.

When counting in binary, it works the same way, but the highest value for each digit is one, so you count up on the lowest digit like this: `0, 1`.  Then you have to add the second digit and count up again: `10, 11`.  Then you need to add a third digit (e.g. `100`) and do it all again on the first two.  By the time you get to `111`, you will have listed every possibly combination of 1's and 0's in a three digit binary number.

So, if you think of the space between each letter as a digit in a binary number, where 0 means no space and 1 means there is a space, then all you have to do is count up from 0 to the highest value in a binary number that is the same number of digits as the length of your word, minus 1.  So, for instance, with the word `TEST`, the the counting would look like this:

- `000` = `TEST`
- `001` = `TES T`
- `010` = `TE ST`
- `011` = `TE S T`
- `100` = `T EST`
- ...